# using the Try Ubuntu / Live with 512mb of ram?

Tags: live-cd

I've tried 14.04 and 12.04 ISOs which both successfully bring me to the desktop but there isn't enough ram to do anything and the OS crashes almost immediately after opening even just the dashboard or a few simple apt-get commands.

Is there some stuff I can kill safely or some boot parameters I can choose to make this work?

I'm in the process of trying other ISOs to get this working but this is not ideal since it is a hosted service.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try Xubuntu or Lubuntu, which are somewhat lightweight. Get them here:

- http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu

But honestly, 512MB simply isn't going to cut it with modern desktop Linuxes. See the [Ubuntu System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) and get more information on [Low Memory Systems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems).

What you might do, depending on your requirements, is install a commandline system, and then install one of the ultra lightweight desktops, as described in detail on the Low Memory page I linked.

Comment: +1 for https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems